# How to get the Unicode representation of Arabic strings in Django?

Tags: python, django, unicode, python-2.x

I'm wondering how to get the Unicode representation of Arabic strings like `سلام` in Python?

The result should be `\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645`

I need that so that I can compare texts retrieved from mysql db and data stored in redis cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an actual Unicode string, you can do

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = u'سلام'
print s.encode('unicode-escape')
```

**output**

```
\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645
```

The `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` directive is purely to tell the interpreter that the source code is UTF-8 encoded, it has no bearing on how the script itself handles Unicode.

---

If your script is reading that Arabic string from a UTF-8 encoded source, the bytes will look like this:

```
\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85
```

You can convert that to Unicode like this:

```
data = '\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85'
s = data.decode('utf8')
print s
print s.encode('unicode-escape')
```

**output**

```
سلام
\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645
```

Of course, you do need to make sure that your terminal is set up to handle Unicode properly.

Note that

```
'\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645'
```

is a plain (byte) string containing 24 bytes, whereas

```
u'\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645'
```

is a Unicode string containing 4 Unicode characters.

You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Well while this works in terminal, I need to assign the output to a new variable. It can not be done using `print` in my views.py. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: @supermario Something like this should work:  `a = s.encode('unicode-escape')`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Python 2.x, you'll not be able to use `encode`. You'll need to use the `unicode` function to cast the string to a unicode object.

```
> f='سلام'
> f
'\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85'
> unicode(f, 'utf-8') # note: you need to pass the encoding parameter in or you'll 
                      # keep having the same problem.
u'\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645'
> print unicode(f, 'utf-8')
سلام
```

I'm not sure what library you're using to fetch the content, but you might be able to fetch the data as unicode initially.

```
> f = u'سلام'
> f
u'\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645'
> print f.encode('unicode-escape')
\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645
> print f
سلام
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepend your string with `u` in python 2.x, which makes your string a unicode string. Then you can call the `encode` method of a unicode string.

```
arabic_string = u'سلام'
arabic_string.encode('utf-8')
```

Output:

```
print arabic_string.encode('utf-8')
'\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85'
```

Comment: This yeilds an error: `'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Which python version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

For python 2.7

```
string = 'سلام'
new_string = unicode(string)
```

Comment: When I print out `string` in the terminal it is still `سلام`. In addition the comparison does not take place as expected.

Comment: sorry just assign it